# how fill NA in a column with another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to fill NA column of column B with one row above column A.

example

```
           A              B
          20:12:00    40:34:00
          04:34:00        NA
          12:35:00    03:19:00
          12:23:00        NA
```

output   : for first NA one row above of NA in column A is 20:12:00 and for second is 12:35:00

```
           A              B
          20:12:00    40:34:00
          04:34:00    20:12:00
          12:35:00    03:19:00
          12:23:00    12:35:00
```

I was trying to use for and solve it but I couldn't

```
     for (i in 2:nrow(N1))
    df[i,51] = ifelse(is.na(df[i,51]), df[i-1,50],df[i,51])
```

where 51 is B and 50 is A. I get error and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you please post the error message so we can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(B = if_else(is.na(B), lag(A), B))
#         A        B
#1 20:12:00 40:34:00
#2 04:34:00 20:12:00
#3 12:35:00 03:19:00
#4 12:23:00 12:35:00
```

I'm unclear on the data type of your column vectors (to avoid such ambiguities it's better to share data using `dput`). Here I assume that they are `factor`s which I then convert to `chr` vectors.

---

Or in base R (thanks @Shree)

```
df$B <- with(df, ifelse(is.na(B), c(NA, A[-nrow(df)]), B)
```

Comment: could you plz describe how it works? I mean how it goes one row above of NA?

Comment: @hghg `dplyr::lag(x)` returns the entry `i-1` at position `i`. Take a look at the output of `dplyr::lag(1:3)`.

Comment: Error: Error: `false` must be a character vector, not a `hms/difftime` object

Comment: I edited my post with something that I was trying, could you plz check it also

Comment: @hgh Please share sample data in an unambiguous format, e.g. using `dput`.

Comment: I think OP's columns A and B are of different types so `if_else` is throwing error.

Comment: @Shree Yup, that's why I asked OP for sample data in an unambiguous format.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `coalesce` here

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(B = coalesce(B, lag(A)))
#      A        B
#1 20:12:00 40:34:00
#2 04:34:00 20:12:00
#3 12:35:00 03:19:00
#4 12:23:00 12:35:00
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("20:12:00", "04:34:00", "12:35:00", "12:23:00"
), B = c("40:34:00", NA, "03:19:00", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: I will give you my put data,

Comment: structure(list(dep = structure(c(43200, 84600, 10740, 43500, 
44700, 58500, 10740, 59400, 10740), class = c("hms", "difftime"
), units = "secs"), start = c("11:00:00", "12:00:00", NA, "07:30:00", 
"12:05:00", "12:25:00", "16:15:00", "07:05:00", "16:30:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

Comment: start=B and dep=A